# Loop through files batch file

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, for-loop, echo

Need this to list all filenames with out the path information. The echo comes out with nothing in it. Any ideas? See code below.

```
For %%A in ("C:\temp\*.dmo") do (
set name=%%~nxA
echo %name%
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [setlocal enabledelayedexpansion](http://batcheero.blogspot.ca/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html). Otherwise the variable is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable inside of a loop, you have to use enabledelayedexpansion to access it.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%A in ("C:\temp\*.dmo") do (
   set name=%%~nxA
echo !name!
)
Pause
```

Or Just:

```
For %%A in ("C:\temp\*.dmo") do (
  echo %%~nxa
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For %%A in ("C:\temp\*.dmo") do (
    set name=%%~nxA
    call echo %%name%%
)
Pause
```

Sigh. Go figure.